# How can I import URL from google calendars to google sheets using Appscript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, calendar, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am writing an Appscript that automatically imports google calendar events into google sheets. I do however seem to be experiencing problems with importing the URL to be able to link to the calendar event.

Is there a function that will allow me to do this easily, alternatively, does anyone know of a way of doing it that doesn't involve advanced services.

Thanks in advance

PS. Here is what I have working so far, a bit of a hash of stuff that I have seen online. Apologies if its not good code.

I'm struggling with getting the URL for the calendar invite.

```
function calendar_importer(){

//
// Import google calendar events into google sheets.
//
// This code retrieves events between the current date and any date in the future.
// It logs the results in the current spreadsheet starting at cell A2 listing the events,
// dates/times, etc and even calculates event duration (via creating formulas in the spreadsheet) and formats the values.
//
// I do re-write the spreadsheet header in Row 1 with every run, as I found it faster to delete then entire sheet content,
// change the parameters, and re-run my exports versus trying to save the header row manually...so be sure if you change
// any code, you keep the header in agreement for readability!
//
// 1. Please modify the value for mycal to be YOUR calendar email address or one visible on your MY Calendars section of your Google Calendar
// 2. Please modify the values for events to be the date/time range you want and any search parameters to find or omit calendar entires
// Note: Events can be easily filtered out/deleted once exported from the calendar
//
// This script is triggered to run once every 5 minutes, doing this will wipe the spreadsheet in its entirity and download a new set of data.
// This way only the most up to date information is displayed from the calendar.
//

// Enter the address of the calendar you wish to download onto the google spreadsheet below. 
var mycal = "edmsmedical@gmail.com";

// Request calendar from google calendars
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

// Calculate today + 365 days for rolling yearly end date.
var EndDate = new Date();
EndDate.setDate(EndDate.getDate()+365);

// Set the desired dates for the spreadsheet to show below. () denotes todays date and will only download events from and including todays date until the set end date.
// Should you wish to select specific dates enter a date and time value in the () for start and end date.
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(), new Date(EndDate));

// Activates sheet so that it can be cleared as per next instruction.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

// Uncomment this next line if you want to always clear the spreadsheet content before running - Note people could have added extra columns on the data though that would be lost.
sheet.clearContents();  

// Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A1:N1 - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter
// of the getRange entry below
var header = [["Date", "Event Details", "Staffing", "Location", "Start", "End", "Duration", "Calendar Link"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,8);
range.setValues(header);

// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calulated ROW 2 (i+2)
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+2;
var myformula_placeholder = '';
// Matching the "header=" entry above, this is the detailed row entry "details=", and must match the number of entries of the GetRange entry below.

//*var splitEventId = events[i].getId().split('@');
//*var eventURL = "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=" + Utilities.base64Encode(splitEventId[0] + "&ctz=Ect/GMT" );
//*some work required to complete the URL framework - what format does google use to link URLs
//*var EventId = events[i].getId();


var details=[[events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getCreators(), "eventURL"]]
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,8);
range.setValues(details);

var cell=sheet.getRange(row,7);

// Calculation for event duration, displayed in HH:MM
cell.setFormula('=HOUR(F' +row+ '-E' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(F' +row+ '-E' + row +')/60)');

}
}
```

Comment: If you have code, then include it in your question. You'll get higher-quality answers and get them faster than you otherwise would.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [Apps Script Document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) and [Google Apps Script Quickstart (for Calendar)](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/apps-script):

> The advanced Calendar service allows you to use the public Google [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) in Apps Script. Much like Apps Script's [built-in Calendar service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar), this API allows scripts to access and modify the user's Google Calendar, including additional calendars that the user is subscribed to. In most cases, the built-in service is easier to use, but this **advanced service provides a few extra features**, including setting the background color for individual events.

One way to check the contents of the variable `event` is use `Logger.log`. You can try this sample code:

```
function listUpcomingEvents() {
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var optionalArgs = {
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    showDeleted: false,
    singleEvents: true,
    maxResults: 10,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  };
  var response = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, optionalArgs);
  var events = response.items;
  if (events.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      var event = events[i];
      Logger.log(event)
      var when = event.start.dateTime;
      if (!when) {
        when = event.start.date;
      }
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, when);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No upcoming events found.');
  }
}
```

If you will check the [**`Events`**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) Resource :

> htmlLink
>
> - An absolute link to this event in the Google Calendar Web UI. Read-only.

Also here is a tutorial : [Export from Calendar to Sheet using Apps Script](http://www.mousewhisperer.co.uk/drivebunny/export-from-calendar-to-sheet-using-apps-script/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, are you saying that in order to get the html link for each event I have to enable advanced Calendar Service?

Comment: yup, you might want to check this filed [enhancement for Google Apps Script](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1456).